# Can't add attachments

Tags: php, email, attachment

Good afternoon,

I can't send attachments within my emails send from website, but it does do see the attachment. How can I add the attachment to the emails send.
I do see text like:

--451b4ac97a84a2205e1d116ef096f765
Content-Type:"image/jpeg; name="testbeeld.jpg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testbeeld.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: 66045

in my body.
Thanks for taking a look into it.

```
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['File_upload']))
{
$recipient_email    = $_POST['email2']; //recepient
$from_email         = $_POST['email']; //from email using site domain.
$subject            = $_POST['title']; //email subject line

$sender_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
$sender_message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message
$attachments = $_FILES['File_upload'];

$file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
$boundary = md5("keukenaanbod.nl");

if($file_count > 0){ //if attachment exists
    //header
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'.
               'From: info@keukenaanbod.nl' . "\r\n".
               'Reply-To: ' . $sender_email . '' . "\r\n" .
               'Cc: ' . $sender_email . '' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion().
               'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n';


    //message text
    $body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:\r\n\"" . $sender_message . "\"\r\n\r\n\r\n";

    //attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){      
        if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){

            if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) //exit script and output error if we encounter any
            {
                $mymsg = array(
                1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
                2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
                3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
                4=>"No file was uploaded",
                6=>"Missing a temporary folder" );
                die($mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]);
            }

            //get file info
            $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
            $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
            $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

            //read file
            $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=" . $file_name . "\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file_name . "\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
            $body .= $encoded_content;
        }
    }

}else{ //send plain email otherwise
           $headers =   "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n".
                        "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n".
                        'From: info@keukenaanbod.nl' . "\r\n".
                        'Reply-To: ' . $sender_email . '' . "\r\n" .
                        'Cc: ' . $sender_email . '' . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
           $body = $sender_message;
}

 $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{      
    header('Location: /verzenden-gelukt?id='. $id .'');
}else{
    die('Email kon helaas niet verzonden worden, u dient direct uit te zoeken wat er gaande is!');  
}
}


}
```

Comment: phpmailer's a lot easier to use for this

Comment: Yes probably, but I don't wanna use phpmailer. This worked before, something changed and I need to figure out what.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail 3 secs. on Google ;-)

Comment: I saw that post, isn't realy helping me here. As I said everything is working (it even sees the filename, type and size and posts it in the email). But the attachment isn't shown.
$encoded_content is shown as a huge string for the image. Not the image itself.

Comment: take the example from an answer in that Q&A. If it fails, then something is failing. Make sure the form's ok - Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see if anything comes of it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the following code, this will output a file as attachment (multiple files are allowed) and placed plain text above the added attachment if set.

Hope someone has a good use for it.

```
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['File_upload']))
{
$recipient_email    = $_POST['email2']; //recepient
$from_email         = $_POST['email']; //from email using site domain.
$subject            = $_POST['title']; //email subject line

$sender_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
$sender_message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message
$attachments = $_FILES['File_upload'];

$file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
$boundary = md5(time());
$eol = "\r\n";

if($file_count > 0){ //if attachment exists
    //header
    $headers = 'From: email@domain.nl<email@domain.nl>' . $eol; 
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $sender_email . '<' . $sender_email . '>' . $eol;
    $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $sender_email . $eol;
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . time() . " TheSystem@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">" . $eol; 
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" . phpversion() . $eol;
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"" . $eol; 


    //message text
    //$body = "--" . $boundary . $eol;
    //$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    //$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    //$body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;

    //attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){      
        if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){

            //get file info
            $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
            $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
            $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

            //read file
            $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

            $body = "--". $boundary . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
            $body .= "Er is gereageerd op jouw keuken aanvraag, reageer op deze mail om in contact te komen:". $eol . $sender_message . $eol . $eol;
            $body .= "--" . $boundary . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Type: " . $file_type. "; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol; 
            $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
            $body .= $encoded_content . $eol . $eol;
        }
    }

}else{ //send plain email otherwise
           $headers =   "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n".
                        "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n".
                        'From: mail@domain.nl' . "\r\n".
                        'Reply-To: ' . $sender_email . '' . "\r\n" .
                        'Cc: ' . $sender_email . '' . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
           $body = $sender_message;
}

 $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{      
    header('Location: /verzenden-gelukt?id='. $id .'');
}else{
    die('Email kon helaas niet verzonden worden, u dient direct uit te zoeken wat er gaande is!');  
}
}


}
```